# SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: missing keyword when use case when in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle to calculate some column in table

this is my LOG0104M table:

```
PRODUCT_CODE    PRODUCT_NAME   PRODUCT_CAT     TOTAL_QUANTITY     PACKING_STYLE
  112677          AP-1516D         AP               65                  30
```

my recipe:

```
FULLBOX = TOTAL_QUANTITY / PACKING_STYLE
SPARE_QUANTITY = TOTAL_QUANTITY - FULLBOX * PACKING_STYLE

 condition:
   if SPARE_QUANTITY = 0 => SPARE_QUANTITY = 0
   if SPARE_QUANTITY >=1 => SPARE_QUANTITY = 1
```

my query:

```
SELECT 
 L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY 
 , L04.PRODUCT_CODE 
 , L04.PRODUCT_NAME

 , CASE WHEN 
    SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) = 0 
 THEN 
    SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) = 0 
 ELSE
    SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) >= 1
 THEN 
    SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) = 1
    END
 END AS SPARE_QUANTITY
 , L04.PRODUCT_CAT 
FROM 
    LOG0104M L04
```

When I run my query, I get this error:

> SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: missing keyword

How can I fix the problem? Many thanks

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  Your query is rife with errors.

Comment: i don't know you need what more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `ELSE` statement being used as an `if/else` You should use`CASE` in your query like this:

```
SELECT L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY 
      ,L04.PRODUCT_CODE 
      ,L04.PRODUCT_NAME
      ,CASE 
          WHEN SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) = 0  THEN 0
          WHEN SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE) >= 1 THEN 1
          ELSE SUM(L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L04.PACKING_STYLE) * L04.PACKING_STYLE)
       END AS SPARE_QUANTITY
      ,L04.PRODUCT_CAT 
FROM LOG0104M L04
GROUP BY L04.TOTAL_QUANTITY 
        ,L04.PRODUCT_CODE 
        ,L04.PRODUCT_NAME
        ,L04.PRODUCT_CAT
        ,L04.PACKING_STYLE
```

Comment: hi @Juan Medina: it seem happen an error: SQL Error [979] [42000]: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: so, could you modify it more ?

Comment: Updated my answer with the GROUP BY